# When crystal report calls an error 80040154 class not registered (exception from HRESULT)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

I am using visual studio 2010 which is 32 bit software and i run this software on 64bit OS.
I make a windows based application using c# and crystal report.

I have successfully deployed my project which has platform target: x86.
This project successfully run on 32 bit windows 7 but when click on print button which calls crystal report object, Windows show an error

> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT :0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

i can't understand the above problem. I searched on google but no found perfect solution of this problem.

Comment: have you thought about right clicking on the executable and changing the compatibility on the 64 bit machine to windows 7?

Comment: cant understand

Comment: on the 64bit machine, what is the name of the application that calls Crystal Reports..? goto that application right click on the .exe file and select compatibility and set it to windows 7

Comment: not work  your suggestion